# Collapse multiline block quote, preserving lines?

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a preprocessor in Java for a language that supports traditional C-style block quotes, of the form:

```
/* Block quote on a single line. */
```

or:

```
/*
  Block quote on multiple lines.
*/
```

The first task of the preprocessor is to “collapse” these block quotes to zero-length strings **but preserve any line breaks** within the quote.  This is necessary so that down the line, any compilation errors can refer the programmer back to the line number in the original (pre-preprocessed!) source code.

Right now, my preprocessor can find and collapse block quotes with Java pattern matching:

```
String open = “/\\*”;  // the initial slash-star
String body = “(.*?)”; // any char, zero or more, reluctantly
String close = “\\*/“; // the ending star-slash

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(open + body + close, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceCode);

sourceCode = m.replaceAll(“”);
```

But, this approach does not preserve line numbering — any multiline block quotes get collapsed to a single line.  Thus:

```
1: /*
2: Multiline block quote.
3: */
4: 
5: println(“I was coded on line 5.”);
```

will preprocess to:

```
1:
2:
3: println(“I was coded on line 5.”);
```

but it should end up as:

```
1:
2:
3:
4:
5: println(“I was coded on line 5.”);
```

Is there a way I can collapse block quotes while preserving line numbering?

Comment: This can be error prone, but perhaps try it like this in Java `(?:^/\*(?=(?:(?!\*/|/\*)[\s\S])*\R\h*\*/)|\G(?!^))(?<=^/\*(?:(?!\*/|/\*)[\s\S]){0,10000})(\R)(?:(?!\*/).*|\*/)` https://regex101.com/r/0QWJGH/1 and https://ideone.com/Xl3cu8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I made a custom method:

```
  //compressBlockComments(String)
  private String compressBlockComments(String source) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("/\\*[\\s\\S]*?\\*/").matcher(source);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(source);
    int offset = 0; //keep track of how many chars have been removed

    while (m.find()) { //Loop through pattern matches
      String blockComment = m.group();
      IntStream onlyNewlines = blockComment.chars().filter(c -> c == '\n');
      int countOfNewlines = (int)onlyNewlines.count();
      String compressed = "\n".repeat(countOfNewlines); //empty string if count == 0

      //Replace the block comment with a compressed string, offsetting
      //to account for the number of chars already removed.
      sb = sb.replace(m.start() - offset, m.end() - offset, compressed);

      //Increment offset with the number of chars removed in this iteration.
      offset += blockComment.length() - countOfNewlines;
    } //while

    return sb.toString();
  }
```

This has proved effective in my testing on source files with block quotes of various lengths and content.